# Why did Sirius have such a large Motorbike?

Tags: harry-potter

In the question [Sirius Black and his motorbike](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18537/sirius-black-and-his-motorbike) it is revealed why Sirius gave Hagrid his motorbike, but as I was re-reading this paragraph in the book:

> " -and a huge motorbike fell out of the air and landed on the road in front of them.
>   If the motorbike was huge, it was nothing to do with the man sitting astride in it."

The motorbike is clearly big enough for Hagrid to sit comfortably in it, and is described as being "huge"- however, if the motorbike belonged to Sirius, why did he have such a large one?

Comment: Clearly, he was compensating for something.

Comment: Huge motorbikes contribute to the cool factor though! Sirius seems like the type of guy who'd use that.

Comment: Hagrid might have also cast an enlargement charm using his umbrella (something which he may have had a lot of practice with given his size). Or, alternately, Rowling might not have settled on that being Sirius's motorbike when she started writing it.

Comment: @SeanDuggan or sirius enlarged it for hagrid, shouldnt be to hard to do at sirius level of skill, vs hagrids level of might blow this bike the F up lol.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

What do we know for a **fact**:

1. Sirius owns a motorcycle that can fly
2. Sirius gives motorcycle to Hagrid
3. The motorcycle is described as big, big enough to fit a half giant Hagrid.

What we can safely **assume**:

1. Motorcycle was muggle-manufactured.
2. Sirius enchanted the motorcycle himself.

What **assumptions** are less safe, but still very **reasonable**:

1. The motorcycle was manufactured at a normal size.
2. Sirius being a normal sized human would ride uncomfortably in an over-large bike.

What **conclusions** these could lead us to.

1. Sirius upon handing the bike over to Hagrid the night of Lily and James' deaths, enlarges it for Hagrid.
2. Hagrid himself enlarges the bike after being given it.
3. The bike itself was enchanted to fit the rider (similar to both the Weasleys' car and the Ministry's cars).

**Canon** info to further our ideas:

1. Cars are shown to be magically enhanced

   a. motorcycle can fly

   b. Weasleys' car can fly, become invisible, and has some enchantment to enlarge the cabin to fit more people/luggage.

   c. the Ministry owns cars that are magically enchanted to also have more room than physically possible.
2. Sirius is an accomplished wizard, probably similar in skill or better than M. Weasley.
3. Hagrid has been shown to be able to enlarge things magically, like his pumpkins.

**My belief**.

The bike itself was enchanted to fit the rider.

This fits best with other enchantments we have seen on other cars, where the car would magically enlarge to fit the riders and luggage.

Comment: "Engorgio!!" + umbrella = oversized bike

Comment: This is reinforced by the description of Sirius' bike in the "[Harry Potter: The Prequel](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_Prequel)". Since the police don't note that the bike is outsized ( something they would surely have spotted), we can assume that it's normal sized.

Comment: I might be missing something, but if the bike adjusted itself to fit the rider, wouldn't it re-adjust to fit Sirius here?

Comment: @Richard - true, but remember that muggles tend to not notice a lot of magic... Knight Buses, invisible houses etc. **Harry**: But the Muggles! Can't they see us? 
**Stan Shunpike**: Muggles? They don't see nothing, do they?

Comment: @JonStory - I feel that a policeman would instantly notice (and remark upon) a massively oversized motorcycle. It would probably be the oddest thing they'd seen that day.

Comment: You'd think we'd have noticed a purple triple decker bus travelling at 100 mph, too... That's the entire point of what I'm saying, some magic objects are 'shielded' from muffles (for want of a better word)

Comment: @JonStory things like the knight bus and the weasleys car  would probably be visible if they did not install an invisibility button, as in the case of the weasleys car, and the knight bus is obviously running heavily enchanted as it forces buildings out of its way, hops around England in minutes. Sirius bike on the other hand, since it obviously wasn't invisible since they saw it, probably did not contain such anti-muggle precautions, because simply, Sirius doesn't give one F if a muggle sees him, hes kinda a BAMF.

Comment: 'The knight bus is obviously running heavily enchanted' ... What, and the flying motorbike with built in magical weapons, isn't? Sirius isn't a complete idiot and was fighting Voldemort, it stands to reason he wouldn't want to draw excess attention with his motorbike

Comment: @JonStory the point of a motorcycle is to draw attention. im not saying he couldn't add more features, but the fact that the muggles saw a perfectly normal sized motorcycle, leads us to believe that it wasn't enchanted to confuse muggles, since as my answer states, a large motorcycle doesn't make sense when you the rider physically don't fit.   its more logical to assume that the motorcycle was infact normal sized, then it is to assume that it was a normal bike enchanted to be larger, and then enchanted to look normal.

Comment: Or perhaps it was designed like the room of requirement, and is as large while appearing as small as necessary

Comment: @JonStory which is my proposed conclusion to my answer, the bike is enchanted to fit the rider.

Comment: Oh sorry, the person talking to me switched :) I wasn't disagreeing with you, just with Richard that a muggle wouldn't see the real state, only the magically modified one

Comment: Extra bike info: [What brand/model was Sirius Black's Muggle motorbike?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/58820/21267)

Comment: Alternately, it could just be a bike that's normally huge. Being made in England probably eliminates the chances of that, but [they do come in large sizes](http://www.strangevehicles.com/images/content/161921.jpg)

Answer (score 9):

An excerpt from the [HP wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sirius_Black's_motorbike):

> **Magic made it much larger than when it was manufactured**, emitting a very loud roar. When Hagrid rides it, it is large enough to fit him, a half-giant, and still can carry an ordinary-size person in its sidecar,. Another spell made it able to fly, fast enough to compete with a broomstick.

I think Sean had the right idea; the bike was enlarged after Sirius lent it to Hagrid.

Comment: What is the basis for this assertion in the wiki though?

Comment: @milk way better than any of my first answers ever were, welcome to Stack Exchange Scifi/fantasty :D

Comment: Wikia isn't canon, it's just something random people typed on the internet. Sorry, -1